# Android - Google+ share status fails and Google Play Services crashes

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

In my app, I am posting stuff on Google plus, but after recent library updates. When I click for posting on Google Plus from my app, the Google Play Services crashes with following error:

```
Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 19643
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.k.a.aj.a(SourceFile:72)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.audience.a.e.<init>(SourceFile:63)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.audience.a.e.<init>(SourceFile:53)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.audience.a.d.<init>(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.sharebox.al.a(SourceFile:213)
        at android.support.v4.app.ax.c(SourceFile:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.ax.d(SourceFile:499)
        at android.support.v4.app.ax.b(SourceFile:646)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.sharebox.al.a(SourceFile:192)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.sharebox.ShareBoxActivity.a(SourceFile:525)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.sharebox.au.a(SourceFile:810)
        at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.ce.a(SourceFile:214)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.v.d(SourceFile:200)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.u.handleMessage(SourceFile:136)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

following is my code I am using for Posting :

```
 Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(getActivity())
        .setType("text/plain")
        .setText(text)
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link))
        .getIntent();

fragment.startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

after refering this link - [Android - Google+ share status fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235268/android-google-share-status-fails) . I tried to use **'ShareCompat.IntentBuilder'** approach, but it doesn't allow to add a link programmatically and hence we have to add a link in text which is posted with **'setText()'**. And hence the hyper link appears to be normal text.

So, If anybody has faced this issue and have resolved it, then please help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the addStream in ShareCompat.IntentBuilder refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.html#addStream(android.net.Uri)

Comment: haven't tried for addStream() but tried the setStream() but It is used to give the link of Media(Image/Video etc.) on Local fileSystem(SdCard). And refering from this link - http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.de/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html I think there isn't any way to post a link except for the 'setText()'.

Comment: Actually the 'setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link))' in PlusShare.Builder is exactly fulfilling my need and in 'ShareCompat.IntentBuilder' approach another issue is, even though I have specified the package name in intent when I set the type as 'image/jpeg' it gives me chooser for 'Google+' and 'Photos' app and even the dialog appears to be different as compared to previous approach. So, any one can help in resolving the crash would be appreciated. My code for 'ShareCompat.IntentBuilder' approach is :

Comment: IntentBuilder shareIntentbuBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity());
  if (uri != null) {
   shareIntentbuBuilder.setStream(uri).setType("image/jpg");

  } else {
   shareIntentbuBuilder.setType("text/plain"); 
  }
        Intent shareIntent = shareIntentbuBuilder
                .setText(text + " " + link)
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

  fragment.startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);

Comment: Actually that link you posted previously was for showing html content in TextView and my requirement is to put hyperlink in setText() method of ShareCompat approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this issue might be because of buggy build. Now I am unable to reproduce this issue. Everything is working fine.